# html svg tag path stroke outline angle

Tags: html, css, svg

How do I erase the angled part of the edge of the outline?

this is my code

```
<svg width="240", height="120" style="margin-top:100px;">
    <path 
        d="M 190,0 
           L58, 0
           Q0 0 0 60
           Q0 120 58 120 
           L190 120
           Q240 120 240 90" 
        stroke-opacity="1" 
        fill-opacity="1" 
        fill="transparent" 
        stroke="black" 
        stroke-width="12" 
        stroke-linejoin="round" 
        stroke-linecap="round">
    </path>
</svg>
```

and result

[image]

Comment: Half your stroke is falling outside the svg canvas. Use a viewBox attribute like so: `<svg width="240" viewBox="-6 -6 252 132">` . Please observe the negative x and y where 6 is half stroke-width. Also the svg canvas is wider and higher by one stroke-width.

Comment: thanks for your comment and hint !! :) 
It works!!